# Displaying Domes In KML

Tags: kml, google-earth

I am attempting to display a dome shape on KML. I have already made the shape, but the shape is highlighted strangely, such that only one half of the dome is visible, while the other half appears very transparent. Does anyone know how I can change this?
Additionally, I would like to display a line which cuts through the dome. When I do this, the part of the line which is encapsulated by the dome is invisible until I scroll in very far. Is there a way to change this?

Images: https://postimg.org/image/49r3nogap/ (trajectory), https://postimg.org/image/3w2pvqzzr/ (dome)

Comment: If you can share your KML file, we can help debug.